# Spacing issue from the left and right side in Mobile

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have used a  tag and set the property for this `<div style="margin:0 auto; ">` and it is working fine. But i have used one more in this above  and set the float as below

```
.gallery-div{ background:url(images/gallery-bg.png) repeat-y; 
float: left;
width:101px;
margin:2px 2px  0px 2px;
border-bottom:2px #9b9b9b solid;
}
```

The problem is it is appearing in left side not in center. If remove

```
float: left; then it appear one below the other like that.
```

See the below screen shots

[image: Gallery apper in left side]

Please help me any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin: 0 auto;` in the CSS file rather than inline.
Also, the second margin will conflict so comment that out.
Get back to me then and let me know how that works for you.

Comment: i tried this earlier but didn't get the desired result. see my code http://paste.org/54000

Comment: It looks like you're not actually placing each result in a parent div to apply the margin setting to. Try that, then it should work.

Comment: Oh... I just noticed you mentioned it works on Android but not on iPhone. I think this might be the browser. Try downloading another browser on your iPhone and access it from there. If it works, then it's browser specific, and you need to apply a fix explixitly to that browser.

Comment: ok but i have more question can we use div left to right without using float?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by div left to right. Do you want to not use float or something? If you don't, is there a reason why?

Comment: As you have not replied, I can only assume what you have asked is answered with this fiddle I have made for you. I hope it answers your question. The top does not have center-aligned content, whereas the bottom does.

  **[Click here to see the fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/FJv6A/)**

Answer (score 0):

Dont have your exact html that we can try out. You should try putting a mock on [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net). But here are a few things I can think of.

If you need one next to another, you either need float, or position defined as absolute/relative. After that, play around with the left and right margins to have the exact margin set so as to get it to the center.

See, I added margin-left here. try working with different numbers there so that you get it to the center

```
.gallery-div{ background:url(images/gallery-bg.png) repeat-y; 
float:left;
width:101px;
margin:2px 2px  0px 2px;
margin-left:30px;
border-bottom:2px #9b9b9b solid;
}
```

Comment: i have used your suggestion but not working, its working fine Android phone, but when i checking it on iphone its not working